# Associating a matroid to a uniform hypergraph

Tags: reference-request, hypergraph, matroid-theory

For a fixed ground set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and for any matroid $M$ on $[n]$, specified as a collection of bases $B_M$, the corresponding *matroid basis polytope* $P_M$ is defined to be the convex hull of the indicator vectors of elements in $B_M$.  It follows easily that each such indicator vector will be a vertex of $P_M$, and all the indicator vectors have the same *Hamming weight* (number of ones), which is equal to the rank of the matroid $M$.

I am interested in matroid constructions that could be associated in some *structured* way to polytopes, whose vertices are $\{0,1\}$-vectors with the same Hamming weight, but which need not be matroid basis polytopes themselves.  In other words, the question is the following: consider a $k$-uniform hypergraph $H$ on the vertex set $[n]$.  Is there a matroid that could be associated to $H$ in some structured sense?

My motivation for this is one such construction by Amini and Branden (Theorem 6.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05878) which turns out to always be a *sparse paving matroid*, given as follows:  Consider a ground set $G_{2n}$ of $2n$ elements, labeled as $G_{2n}=\{1,\ldots,n\}\sqcup\{1',\ldots,n'\}$. For a $k$-uniform hypergraph $H$ on vertex set $[n]$, denote $A'=\{i':i\in A\}$ for each $A\in E(H)$.  The collection
$$B(H)=\binom{G_{2n}}{2k}\setminus\{A\sqcup A':A\in E(H)\}$$
is the collection of bases of a sparse paving matroid.

I would think that the above association of a matroid defined by the collection of bases $B(H)$ (on a ground set of $2n$ elements) to any $k$-uniform hypergraph $H$ (on a vertex set of $n$ elements) is structured, in that each such matroid is sparse paving.  Are there other such structured matroid constructions known, associated to uniform hypergraphs?